# How do I add double quotes to every element in a list column in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe `df` which contains a list column

```
0         1
foo       [foo,bar]
bar       [bar,foo]
```

What is an efficient way to add double quotes to each list element to make the output:

```
0         1
foo       ["foo","bar"]
bar       ["bar","foo"]
```

Please assume there are more than 2 rows

Comment: column 1 is lists of strings or just strings?

Comment: list of strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list comprehension:

```
df["1"] = [[f'"{j}"' for j in i] for i in df["1"]]

print (df)

                1
0  ["foo", "bar"]
1  ["bar", "foo"]
```

Comment: This is a very elegant solution. I would allways prefer a list comprehension over other methods.

Answer (score 0):

You could do,

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({0: ["foo","bar"], 1: ["bar", "foo"]})

df = '"' + df.astype(str) + '"'
```

Result:

```
0   1
0   "foo"   "bar"
1   "bar"   "foo"
```

If you want to do this for a specific column, do:

```
df[0] = '"' + df[0].astype(str) + '"'
```

Result:

```
    0   1
0   "foo"   bar
1   "bar"   foo
```